# How to have operator settings not stored for re-use?

Tags: python, scripting, add-on

I have an add-on that adds an object to the scene and lets you adjust some settings. Is there a way to reset the add-on for each use, so it doesn't use the previous setting on the next object created?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Enable the `SKIP_SAVE` option [when defining the property](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.props.html).

eg:

```
some_property = BoolProperty(options={'SKIP_SAVE'})
```